# jdk.dio.DeviceNotFoundException

Tags: gpio, pi-3

I am currently trying to make a very simple Led example with Raspberry PI 3 Model b. I am using Java ME 8 Embedded instead of PI4j. I have followed the Oracle's tutorial and I did not change anything from what they have shown. The code, I am trying to run is as follows;

```
public class GPIOPinTest implements PinListener, AutoCloseable {

private GPIOPin led1;

public void start() throws IOException {

    led1 = DeviceManager.open(23); //This line of code is problematic

    //The rest is omitted

}
```

Whenever I run the code on the raspberry pi or emulator, it throws "IOException: jdk.dio.DeviceNotFoundException: Device 23 not found" exception.

I could not find, what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution with the help of the discussions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=98641)

The problem was the direction of the assigned pin. 23 in my example. A pin can be input, output or bidirectional (both direction).

If the pin is input by default and wanted to be used as output, that throws the exception, I have mentioned. In order to solve this problem, one should explicitely define the usage of the pin.

I have changed the code above as follows and it works like a charm right now.

```
public class GPIOPinTest implements PinListener, AutoCloseable {

private GPIOPin led1;

public void start() throws IOException {


    GPIOPinConfig config = new GPIOPinConfig.Builder()
               .setPinNumber(23)
               .setDirection(1) //0 means input, 1 means output.
               .setInitValue(true)
               .build();

    //The rest is omitted

}
```

I hope this helps someone...